# How to delete a specific element inside a div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html code,

```
<div id="listing">
Text Message 
<div class="ch">ch 1</div>
<button class="btn" />
<div class="ch">ch 2</div>
<button class="btn" />
<div class="ch">ch 3</div>
<button class="btn" />
<div class="ch">ch 4</div>
<button class="btn" />
</div>
```

If a user click the button with class "btn", it will delete the "ch" div and the corresponding button. 
for example,

```
<div id="listing">
Text Message 
<div class="ch">ch 1</div>
<button class="btn" />
<div class="ch">ch 2</div>
<button class="btn" />
<div class="ch">ch 3</div>
<button class="btn" />
</div>
```

I tried to add ID of div. but It is difficult since the div with class "ch", is dynamically created.

So I want to delete a div that only have className.

Answer (score 3):

> If a user click the div with class "ch", it will delete. for example,

I'm sorry, I completely missed this when first answering your question.

Two ways you can do that:

1. If you hook up a `click` handler, within the call to the handler, `this` will refer to the element that was clicked. So:

   ```
   var list = document.querySelectorAll("#listing .ch");
   var n;
   for (n = 0; n < list.length; ++n) {
       list[n].addEventListener("click", function() {
           this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
       }, false);
   }
   ```
2. But since you say these are *dynamically generated*, I'd use *event delegation*, the fact that clicks bubble up to ancestor elements, and just hook `click` on `#listing`:

   ```
   document.getElementById("listing").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
       // Find the .ch, starting with the element the click originated in
       var ch = e.target;
       while (ch && !ch.className.match(/\bch\b/)) {
           ch = ch.parentNode;
       }
       if (ch) {
           ch.parentNode.removeChild(ch);
       }
   }, false);
   ```

Here's a live example of the delegation version:

```js
document.getElementById("listing").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // Find the .ch, starting with the element the click originated in.
  // You need this loop if there's any possibility of any elements
  // *within* the .ch elements, such as `em` or `strong` or `span`.
  var ch = e.target;
  while (ch && !ch.className.match(/\bch\b/)) {
    ch = ch.parentNode;
  }
  if (ch) {
    ch.parentNode.removeChild(ch);
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="listing">
  Text Message
  <div class="ch">ch 1</div>
  <div class="ch"><em>ch 2</em></div>
  <div class="ch"><strong>ch 3</strong></div>
  <div class="ch">ch 4</div>
</div>
```

---

**Original answer** that missed that relevant point!

On any modern browser, you can do this:

```
document.querySelector("#listing div:nth-child(3)").remove();
```

Live example:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector("#listing div:nth-child(3)").remove();
}, 500);
```

```html
<div id="listing">
Text Message 
<div class="ch">ch 1</div>
<div class="ch">ch 2</div>
<div class="ch">ch 3</div>
<div class="ch">ch 4</div>
</div>
```

On *slightly* older browsers you may need:

```
var element = document.querySelector("#listing div:nth-child(3)");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Live example:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var element = document.querySelector("#listing div:nth-child(3)");
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}, 500);
```

```html
<div id="listing">
Text Message 
<div class="ch">ch 1</div>
<div class="ch">ch 2</div>
<div class="ch">ch 3</div>
<div class="ch">ch 4</div>
</div>
```

Those both use [`:nth-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo), which matches the *n*th child element inside its parent. (Note that it **doesn't** match the *n*th *matching* child, the `div` is just there for clarity.)

They also use `querySelector`, which is supported on all modern browsers, and also IE8.

Comment: how about if it is a button?

Comment: @PinasDeRadio: I assume you're asking about the loop in Option 2. If so: It depends on the kind of button. If it's an `<input type="button">`, you don't need the loop, because they can't have child elements. If it's a `<button>`, you do.

Comment: if the button is click that part of the ch 3?

Comment: @PinasDeRadio: If you mean `<div class="ch"><button>xxxx</button></div>` or `<div class="ch"><input type="button" value="xxxx"></div>`, yes, you need the loop, because the click originates in the button and you need to find its ancestor `div class="ch"` element. Just try it out and find out what works.

Comment: Can I make it <div class="ch"><div class="delete"></div></div> then if user clicked delete div, it will remove the whole "Ch" div?

Comment: instead of ch? i will make it the button?

Comment: @PinasDeRadio: If you want to *only* have clicks on the button or delete div do it, do exactly what's in Option 2, but in the loop check to see if you see the button / delete div on the way to finding the `.ch` element, and only do the `removeChild` at the end if you do. There's no better way to learn this than to experiment with it, use the debugger built into your browser to watch what happens, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="listing">
Text Message 
<div class="ch">ch 1</div>
<div class="ch">ch 2</div>
<div class="ch">ch 3</div>
<div class="ch">ch 4</div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).on('click','.ch',function(){
   $(this).remove();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mazba/hfqkcggh/)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div id="listing">
       Text Message 
       <div class="ch">ch 1</div>
       <div class="ch">ch 2</div>
       <div class="ch">ch 3</div>
      <div class="ch">ch 4</div>
    </div> 
    Simple use each function to get all divs
        $('.ch').click(function(){
          if($(this).text() == 'ch 1'){
            $(this).remove();
          }
        });
output:
<div id="listing">
       Text Message 
       <div class="ch">ch 2</div>
       <div class="ch">ch 3</div>
       <div class="ch">ch 4</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below solution works only if your mark up is as exactly as you have given.

```js
//This solution will not work if the .ch element has another class or has another descendant element
document.querySelector('#listing').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.className = 'ch') { //or if(e.target.classList.contains('ch')){
    this.removeChild(e.target)
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="listing">
  Text Message
  <div class="ch">ch 1</div>
  <div class="ch">ch 2</div>
  <div class="ch">ch 3</div>
  <div class="ch">ch 4</div>
</div>
```

Another choice is to iterate over all the ch elements and then register a click handler to it